# show a number of inputs type text equal to the number of selected files in my input file without send form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Im uploading multiple pdfs at same time, and Im trying to find a method to give a a custom title for each uploaded pdf.

So I thought at first using php, I store a variable to count pdfs that the user selected

```
$countPdfs = count($_FILES['pdfs']['tmp_name']);
```

And then in my form, I have some php where I show a text input to write a title for each pdf that I upload.

```
<div class="galerry">               
    <div class="label">
        <span class="field">Pdfs:</span>
        <input type="file" name="pdfs[]" class="j_gallerypdf" multiple="multiple" accept="application/pdf"  />
        <div class="j_gfalsepdf">Select many pdfs</div>
         <img src="img/upload.png" class="j_gsendpdf"/>
    </div>

   <?php
   if(isset($countPdfs )){
      for($i=1;$i<=$countPdfs ;$i++){
          echo '<div class="label">';
               echo '<span class="field">Pdf Title:</span>';
               echo '<input type="text" name="title" />';
          echo '</div>';
      }
   }
   ?>   
</div>
```

And so If I select 5 pds it shows me 5 text inputs, it is working fine.

**But I need to send my form and only after send form my inputs appear.**

Do you know how can I do this using jQuery? After I select my pdfs in my input file, show the same number of input texts that my number of selected pdfs?

Im already using this jQuery function below to show in my input the number of pdfs that user select:

```
$('.j_gsendpdf').click(function(){
    $('.j_gallerypdf').click().change(function(){
    var numFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;
    $('.j_gfalsepdf').animate({width:'400'}, 500, function(){
        $(this).html('You selected'+ numFiles +'</strong> files.'); 
    });
    });
});
```

But do you know how can I use this numFiles also to open a number of input texts icual to my numFiles variable?

Comment: Instead of: `$(this)[0].files.length;` just use: `this.files.length` (this isn't an answer, just a code improvement).

Comment: Thank you for your improvment tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is the following:

```
// binding a change event-handler to the file-input(s):
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function(){
    // finding the closest '.gallery' element, then finding
    // its descendant 'fieldset' element, removing the 'empty' class
    // (that it has on page-load to hide it while empty):
    var fieldset = $(this).closest('.gallery').find('fieldset').removeClass('empty'),
        // we're using the fileList so we're caching it, the other two are
        // used later (in the for loop):
        files = this.files, curFile, label;

    for (var i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++){
        // caching the 'current file' in the prepared variable:
        curFile = files[i];
        // creating a label element, keeping a reference in the
        // prepared variable:
        label = $('<label />', {
            'html' : 'Change the name of <span class="filename">' + curFile.name + '</span>?'
        // appending the created 'label' to the fieldset:
        }).appendTo(fieldset);

        // creating an 'input' element:
        $('<input />', {
            'type' : 'text',
            // the current value is the current file-name:
            'value' : files[i].name
        // appending that to the created/appended 'label' element:
        }).appendTo(label);
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tzdQ6/).

The above approach relies on the presence of a fieldset identifying where the created`input` elements should be appended, so I've changed your HTML to the following:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <div class="gallery">
        <div class="label"> <span class="field">Pdfs:</span>

            <input type="file" name="pdfs[]" class="j_gallerypdf" multiple="multiple" accept="application/pdf" />
            <div class="j_gfalsepdf">Select many pdfs</div>
            <fieldset class="empty">
                <legend>Titles</legend>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This approach is, however, moderately naive: if you reselect new files from the file input it will create, and append, new `<label>` and `<input>` elements. This could be partially countered (assuming it's not an inconvenience to you, or your users, by removing previously-created elements), using `empty()`: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tzdQ6/1/).

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way.

```
$('.j_gallerypdf').click().change(function(){
    var allFiles = this.files;  
    var numFiles = this.files.length;
    $('.j_gfalsepdf').animate({width:'400'}, 500, function(){
     $(this).html('You selected'+ numFiles +'</strong> files.'); 
     for(var i = 0; i<numFiles; i++) {
        var file = allFiles[i], name = file.name;
        $(this).append('<input type="text" name="title[]" value="'+name+'"/>');
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! It is working fine but have just one problem that Im trying to fix it. The poblem is: If I select only one pdf I have my append of one input (its fine), but then If I select other pdf I have an append of more two pdfs and not only one.